# Efficiently debug stored procedure in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, debugging, stored-procedures, ssms

For years, to debug stored procedures I use a very lame basic approach. I wonder if there is a more modern way or tool to make life easier.

Let's say we ran the stored procedure

`EXECUTE MyCoolProcedure 'Parameter1', 2, 'Parameter3', '2019-11-25'`

And it fails with the error

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MyCoolProcedure, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Divide by zero error encountered.

This `Line 11` part is not particularly helpful because it is not clear how those lines are numbered.

If I click **Modify** on the stored procedure, I see

```
USE [MyCoolDatabase]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[MyCoolProcedure]    Script Date: 11/26/2019 3:01:05 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyCoolProcedure]
(
    @p1 varchar(20),
    @p2 int,
    @p3 varchar(30),
    @p4 smalldatetime
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT -- I bet it fails in here, Line #18
        1 /
        (@p2 - 2
        );
END;
```

Here it is obvious it is failing in the line #18, so probably we just need to add **7** to whatever line number is shown. But you see it is like a rule of thumb.

But let's pretend it's not so obvious what is failing in here, so we need to put some debugging statements around to figure out what is wrong

Write now what I do is I copy the whole content of the procedure declaration and edit it in-place

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyCoolProcedure] DECLARE
(
    @p1 varchar(20) = 'Parameter1',
    @p2 int = 2,
    @p3 varchar(30) = 'Parameter3',
    @p4 smalldatetime = '2019-11-25'
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT -- I bet it fails in here, Line #18
        1 /
        (@p2 - 2
        );
END;
```

This is a bit time consuming and annoying. Ideally as a Visual Studio user, I would prefer to have something like **Attach to process** and **Break on error** functionality.

Am I doing it wrong? Is there a more efficient way to do those repetitive tasks?

Comment: in `SSMS` rather `execute` click `debug` then step into rather over

Comment: @maSTAShuFu it it's ok for simple cases. But in really you need to more debugging statements around the problematic code to see what causes the problem

Comment: well i guess if you'd like to make it harder for yourself then use `sql profiler`

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I don't get it. From the sql profiler I just see that `EXECUTE MyCoolProcedure 'Parameter1', 2, 'Parameter3', '2019-11-25'` part, which doesn't help with the internals

Comment: There are also events for `sp_statement_starting` and `sp_statement_completed` in both Profiler and Extended Events.